# using django application with local host forever

Tags: django, localhost

I wanna create an application for a store to maintain his inventory.I chose django to develop this app with local host, since the size of the data is too small.But, I'm confused how the user can run the command "py manager.py runserver" everytime.Is there any alternative for this to start the server automatically when the system starts, in an windows system.

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: will use windows

Answer (score 0):

As you're using windows you can place your script to this directory

`C:\Users\current_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`

Also, your .py extension should default to `Python Idle`. So the python file you may place over there could be something like this

import os 
os.system('C:/path/to/my/virtualenv/Scripts/python C:/path/to/django/project/manage.py runserver')

Comment: Does the script need the virtual environment activated ?

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer please check this will use the python version you used in your virtualenv.